# Why exactly is a char* cast required in finding the row of a pitched memory address?

Tags: c, cuda

I was reading through the documentation, and got to chapter 3.2.2. I saw the definition and explanation for `cudaMallocPitch()`, and was somewhat confused about accessing certain data members. For example:

```
int width = 64, height = 64;
float* devPtr;
size_t pitch;
cudaMallocPitch(&devPtr, &pitch,
                width * sizeof(float), height);
MyKernel<<<100, 512>>>(devPtr, pitch, width, height);

// Device code
__global__ void MyKernel(float* devPtr,
                         size_t pitch, int width, int height)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < height; ++r) {
        float* row = (float*)((char*)devPtr + r * pitch);
        for (int c = 0; c < width; ++c) {
            float element = row[c];
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the char* cast is required in the definition of row in the second line of MyKernel(). Also, I don't understand why devPtr is a float*. Shouldn't it be a float**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand why the char* cast is required

Because `pitch` is a value in bytes, and casting the pointer to `char*` allows the pitch to be added as a byte offset for the row in the allocation. If there was no cast, the offset would be incorrect by the ratio of the number of bytes in the original type.

> Why devPtr is a `float*`. Shouldn't it be a `float**`?

No.

Pitched memory is a single allocation of contiguous memory, referenced by a single pointer, just like normal memory allocated with `malloc` or `cudaMalloc`. The only thing that is special about it is that it's size is calculated so that the row-wise data stored in the memory can be padded to a length which is optimal/compatible with the memory controller and texture addressing units on the GPU. That is why a pitch is required in the addressing calculations -- the pitch is the size requested including the necessary padding.